# Is it possible to upload a file to server without converting it into NSData?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsdata, nsmutableurlrequest

I am developing an app in which I have to upload a file to server from device, i know how to send file to server using following `NSMutableURLRequest` , but is it possible to store file to server without converting to `NSData`??

I have seen [How upload image in to asp.net server without converting into NSData in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515190/how-upload-image-in-to-asp-net-server-without-converting-into-nsdata-in-iphone) this question but didn't find any solution.

Comment: I don't think so. Let's see what others say.

Comment: It is not possible, you need to convert your data into Bytes to travel on the network.

Comment: All the things transferred on the network is the form of Byte.

Answer (score 0):

Networks are analogue and computer and devices are digital they not understand what is what for them all the things are digital data so I guess now you understand its simply not possible, If you are having any specific problem of converting your file into data and the getting them back, you can go ahead

Answer (score 0):

The data on a network always flows in Bytes irrespective of any platform.. NSData will finally be converted to bytes data before sending it over network.. On higher level your data should be in NSData format but on lower level its on Bytes.. So in ios it will be either Bytes of Data (if you are using NSInputstream to upload data) or NSData (which will finally converted to Bytes again and sent over the Network)